# How to implement a panoramic view with a set of images in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimageview, uiimage

I am having a set of 6-8 images. How can I make a panoramic effect using `UIImageView` like done in `Photosynth` or other panoramic applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for a linear panoramic effect (simply panning left or right), you can use
`UIScrollView` for this. Add the `UIImageViews` as subviews and adjust their frames within the scroll view.

If you're looking for a cubic panoramic effect (panning through 360° on all axes), then take a look at [JAPanoView](https://bitbucket.org/javieralonso/japanoview/).